# How to delete Rows in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub A()
    
    Dim I, Q, C_Count As Integer
    C_Count = Worksheets("0618").Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    
    For I = 7 To C_Count
     
      Q = Worksheets("0618").Cells(9, I).Value
    
      If 0 < Q And Q < 100 Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I - 1, 3).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(2, I).Value
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I - 1, 4).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(9, I).Value
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I - 1, 5).Value = Worksheets("0618").Cells(4, I).Value
      End If
      
    Next
    
 End Sub
```

[The result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNqAH.png)

I want to delete the empty rows with vba code but don't know how to.
Could someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code:

```
Sub Delete()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        'Find the last row of Column A Sheet1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Loop starting from last row to 1 row
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            
            'Check if the value in column A row i is empty
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
            
        Next i
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```